# Bt Socket closed exception

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, kotlin

I am building an app that is supposed to send a file over a Bluetooth socket but for some reason i keep getting the same Exception. The error message says that the socket is already closed but i don't understand how or why it is getting closed before i attempt to read from it. The user is presented with an AlertDialog with options to choose from. they are supposed to: 1. Pair to a device. 2. send file to device (currently labeled 'connect' in dialog). The exception occurs after the devices are paired, when the connect option is selected. when the receiving device attempts to read from socket i get this exception:

```
Process: com.example.zemcd.toofxchange, PID: 1074
      java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
      at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:588)
      at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
      at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
      at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.copyTo(IOStreams.kt:101)
      at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.copyTo$default(IOStreams.kt:98)
      at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.readBytes(IOStreams.kt:117)
      at com.example.zemcd.toofxchange.BluetoothUtils$Companion.receiveFile(BluetoothUtils.kt:82)
      at com.example.zemcd.toofxchange.ListenThread$run$acceptThread$1.run(BluetoothUtils.kt:104)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

below are the functions used for pair, unpair, and connect (to send data) along with the threads subclasses that used:

```
class BluetoothUtils {

companion object {

    var listener: ListenThread? = null

    val _UUID = UUID.fromString("a0e7e4c7-0e4e-43b7-9d18-659192512164")
    val TAG = "BluetoothUtils"

    val receiver = MainBTStatusReceiver()

    fun initPairingServer(adapter: BluetoothAdapter){
        var mmServerSocket: BluetoothServerSocket?
        try {
            var tmp = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(TAG, _UUID)
            mmServerSocket = tmp
            listener = ListenThread(mmServerSocket)
            listener!!.start()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing Bluetooth", ioe)
        }
    }

    fun cancelListener() = listener!!.cancel()

    fun connect(adapter: BluetoothAdapter, device: BluetoothDevice):Unit{
        var btSocket: BluetoothSocket?
        Log.d(TAG, "connect function called")
        if (device.bondState==BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE)return //to prompt user to pair
        try {
            adapter.cancelDiscovery()
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_UUID)
            ConnectThread(btSocket).start()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "error connecting", ioe)
        }
    }

    fun startPair(adapter: BluetoothAdapter, device: BluetoothDevice): Unit{
        adapter.cancelDiscovery()
        Log.d(TAG, device.bondState.toString())
        device.createBond()
    }

    fun unPair(device: BluetoothDevice): Any = device::class.java.getMethod("removeBond").invoke(device)

    fun sendFile(btSocket: BluetoothSocket){
        val out = btSocket.outputStream.buffered()
        out.use {
            val msg = "hello".toByteArray()
            Log.d(TAG, "sending data")
            it.write(msg, 0, msg.size)
            it.flush()
        }
        btSocket.close()
    }

    fun receiveFile(btSocket: BluetoothSocket){
        Log.d(TAG, "receiveFile called")
        val inStream = btSocket.inputStream.buffered()
        //val bytes: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)
        val bytes: ByteArray = inStream.use { it.readBytes(1024)}
        Log.d(TAG, bytes.toString())
        btSocket.close()
    }

}
}

class ListenThread(val btServSock: BluetoothServerSocket) : Thread(){

companion object {
    val TAG = "ListenThread"
}

var btSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null

override fun run() {
    super.run()
    while (true){
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "listening . . . ")
            btSocket = btServSock.accept()
            Log.d(TAG, btSocket.toString() + " was accepted")
            val acceptThread = Thread(Runnable { BluetoothUtils.receiveFile(btSocket!!) })
            acceptThread.start()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", ioe)
            break
        }
    }
}

fun cancel() = btServSock.close()
}

class ConnectThread(val btSocket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread(){

companion object {
    val TAG = "Pairing Thread"
}

override fun run() {
    super.run()

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "attempting to connect")
        btSocket.connect()
        BluetoothUtils.sendFile(btSocket)
    }catch (ioe: IOException){
        Log.e(TAG, "error connecting", ioe)
        btSocket.close()
    }
}
}
```

and they are called like this inside of OnClickListener:

```
ops.forEach { it.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(it.context, it.id.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                when(it.id){
                    R.id.statOp -> {}
                    R.id.connectOp -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "connectOp reached")
                        BluetoothUtils.connect(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), btDevice)
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }
                    R.id.pairOp -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "pairOp reached")
                        mReceiver.setFocus(this@DeviceHolder)
                        BluetoothUtils.startPair(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), btDevice)
                        Log.d(TAG, "start pair complete")
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }
                    R.id.unPairOp -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "unPairOp reached")
                        mReceiver.setFocus(this@DeviceHolder)
                        BluetoothUtils.unPair(btDevice)
                        Log.d(TAG, "unpair complete")
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }
                    R.id.sendOp -> {}
                }
            } }
```

and here is my with resources function:

```
inline fun <T: AutoCloseable, U> withResources(resource: T, fn: (T) -> U) : U{
try {
    return fn(resource)
}finally {
    resource.close()
}
}
```

please help me find my mistake. if other pieces of my code are needed let me know and i will post them. thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems like peer has closed connection, try to reconnect

Comment: @Stanislav I have tried this repeatedly and always get the same result. What do you mean reconnect? Like call creatBond again?

Comment: @Stanislav any idea what could be causing the connection to close early? Any noticeable problem with my code?